# Arduino pyfirmata analog reading problems

Tags: python, arduino, pyfirmata

I am having some problems reading analog values from my **Arduino Mega** using **pyfirmata**.
I use Arduino Mega with a Mega Sensor Shield.
I would like to read analog values from a **HW-201 IR sensor** (pin A5).
I have uploaded the Standard firmata sketch on Arduino IDE, and I am running the following code using Anaconda Spyder:

```
import serial
import serial.tools.list_ports 
from pyfirmata import ArduinoMega, util
from time import sleep

def readArduinoPort():
    COM = []                                                                      
    ports = list(serial.tools.list_ports.comports())
    for p in ports:
        if "Arduino" in p.description:
            COM.append(str(p.device))
    return COM
 
COM = readArduinoPort() 
board = ArduinoMega(COM[0])                                                     

pin = board.get_pin('a:5:i')
it = util.Iterator(board)
it.start()
try:
    while True:
        print(pin.read())
        sleep(0.1)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
```

Now, this code runs just fine the first time I use it, generating numbers close to 1 when the sensor is detecting proximity and numbers close to 0 when not detecting anything.

However, whenever I try to run the Iterator a **second time** (without restarting the kernel), the code generates seemingly random numbers (almost like the pin was floating, like nothing was connected to it).

Any idea why this is happening? Is this a normal behavior?
Thank you!

I already checked these questions that do not entirely address my issue:

- [arduino pyfirmata analog reading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66575038/arduino-pyfirmata-analog-reading)
- [Analog readings on Arduino returns wrong values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2851078/analog-readings-on-arduino-returns-wrong-values)

I have the same result by not having anything pinned to pin A5 of the Arduino Mega.

I wasn't sure, but I tried adding:

```
board.analog[5].enable_reporting()
```

before the iterator and then:

```
board.analog[5].disable_reporting()
```

but nothing changed.

Comment: FYI, there's a SE site just for [arduino.se].

Comment: Thank you for the tip, I was unaware. I'll have a look there as well

Answer (score 0):

### Board Differences

---

I ran into the same problem. I own both a Mega and an Uno and needed to **select the appropriate Board and Processor** in the tools menu:

```
Tools > Board > _board_
Tools > Processor > _processor_
```